# Handling model requirements within the same view?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, nested-forms

First and foremost, thanks for taking time to read and respond to my questions. I really appreciate it.

I'm not looking for the exact code on how to achieve the following but more of a direction or path I should follow.

Users that are logged in can create different courses. I've added a requirement (a provider) for each course and I want the user to have at least one provider associated (using rolify for this) to them before doing so but I'd like this to be on the same view (courses#new)

I've tried the following:

- Nested forms (Doesn't work since I require at least one provider upon course creation)
- Adding the providers#new in a modal on the page (can't call a controller from another one using form_form(@provier)

I've thought of the following:

- Redirect the users to providers#new if they haven't created one first
- Add a modal with a form_tag element that creates a provider and then refreshes the underlying page.

What are your thoughts? Better ideas?

Thanks!
Francis

My courses#new (_form) view

```
<%= simple_form_for(@course) do |f| %>
  <%= f.error_notification %>
    <%= f.input :name %>
    <%= f.input :description, as: :text, input_html: { rows: '2' } %>
    <%= f.association :provider, :value_method => :id, collection:      Provider.with_role(:provider_admin, current_user), input_html: { class: 'input-large' },   include_blank: false %>
  <div class="form-actions">
    <%= f.button :submit, :class => 'btn-primary' %>
    <%= link_to "Cancel", :back, class: 'btn' %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

models/provider.rb

```
class Provider < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :description, :name
  validates :name, :presence => true
  validates :description, :presence => true
  validates :name, :length => { :minimum => 6, :maximum => 100 }
  validates :description, :length => { :minimum => 6, :maximum => 100 }
  has_many :courses

end
```

models/course.rb

```
class Course < ActiveRecord::Base

  attr_accessible :description, :name, :provider_id
  validates :name, :presence => true
  validates :name, :length => { :minimum => 6, :maximum => 100 }
  validates :description, :presence => true
  validates :description, :length => { :minimum => 6, :maximum => 256 }
  validates :provider_id, :presence => true

  belongs_to :provider
  has_many :sessions, :dependent => :destroy

end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I like the idea where you do a redirect in `courses#new` to `providers#new` when `!current_user.provider.any?`.

But I would probably go the nested forms way. You can use one form to create a new course and a new provider if a user doesn't have a provider. Have a look at http://railscasts.com/episodes/196-nested-model-form-revised to get a quick idea. I think that this would be best UI wise.

Comment: The redirect is kinda crap in terms of UX and it's going to be quite confusing for the users. That's why I'd prefer to do it in the same page. For some reason the nested forms wouldn't work correctly and I'm guessing that the fact that a course requires a provider to be set was the culprit. I guess I need the provider to be created *before* the course is saved to the db?

Comment: With your current model the nested form doesn't work. You have to change your attr_accessibles. Have a look at the screencast.